# Set-AzApiManagement with -UserAssignedIdentity is giving Bad Request

Tags: azure, identity, azure-api-management

I am trying to assign a User Assigned Identity to a API Management instance on Azure from Powershell. I have taken reference from below link -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-managed-service-identity#code-try-7

I am trying the same code -

```
# Get an API Management instance
$apimService = Get-AzApiManagement -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $apiManagementName

# Create a user-assigned identity. This requires installation of the "Az.ManagedServiceIdentity" module.
$userAssignedIdentity = New-AzUserAssignedIdentity -Name $userAssignedIdentityName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

# Update an API Management instance
$userIdentities = @($userAssignedIdentity.Id)
Set-AzApiManagement -InputObject $apimService -UserAssignedIdentity $userIdentities
```

but it is always giving me below error message -

`Set-AzApiManagement: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'`

What am I missing? What's wrong with the code? Any immediate help is appreciated!! Thanks in advance..
Am using Powershell..

**Edit**

The API Management instance is already having one User Assigned Identity, I am trying to add another..

Comment: are you trying in PS?

Comment: Yes I am using Powershell

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/38047561-support-for-user-assigned-managed-identity do you mean system assigned?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I am able to add first UserAssignedIdentity if there is no Identity available. But if there is already one there then it is giving me this error..

Comment: how did you add the initial one?

Comment: I had added from Azure Portal - UI. But after your comment, I had removed from there and tried from Powershell and it works with same code above.. but when I tried to add another at that time I am getting this error..
Que - How can I combine both - existing UserAssignedIdentity and new UserAssignedIdentity as string array in Powershell? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
Connect-AzAccount

$userAssignedIdentity = New-AzUserAssignedIdentity -Name "myapi" -ResourceGroupName ""
$userIdentities = @($userAssignedIdentity.Id)

$apimService = Get-AzApiManagement -ResourceGroupName "" -Name "huryApim"

[string[]]$test= $apimService.Identity.UserAssignedIdentity.Keys
[string[]]$test += $userAssignedIdentity.Id

Set-AzApiManagement -InputObject $apimService -UserAssignedIdentity $test
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it works.. I just didn't know how to get existing keys into string[]..